# Track a new remote branch created on GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have already got a local master branch tracking the remote master branch of a github project. Now, a collaborator of mine has created a new branch in the same project, and I want to do the following accordingly:

1. create a new branch locally
2. make this new branch track the newly create remote branch.

How should I do it properly?

Comment: git checkout --track -b <local branch> <remote>/<tracked branch> also works.

Comment: ... or just `git checkout -t <remote>/<whatever>`.  If there's only one remote-tracking branch that ends in `<whatever>` you can even just do `git checkout <whatever>` and git guesses what you mean.

Comment: See also [How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/520650/456814).

Answer (score 308, accepted):

```
git fetch
git branch --track branch-name origin/branch-name
```

First command makes sure you have remote branch in local repository. Second command creates local branch which tracks remote branch. It assumes that your remote name is `origin` and branch name is `branch-name`.

`--track` option is enabled by default for remote branches and you can omit it.

Comment: When I do this, I get a warning: refname 'branch-name' is ambiguous.

Comment: If there is only one remote branch with that branch name, you can just do `git checkout <branchname>` and git will automatically check it out and setup a tracking branch. Just wanted to reiterate what @Mark Longair said above in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262703/how-to-track-a-new-remote-branch-created-on-github#comment14806580_11262703.

Comment: The name of my remote branch is `remotes/origin/develop`? Shouldn't it be just `origin/develop`? Are these the same?

Comment: I had to do `git fetch --all`, otherwise new branches would not be fetched

Comment: How to do this in Eclipse? When I'm done with those `cmd`, eclipse detect the new branch?

Comment: Echoing @mschrimpf, for a special remote (e.g. `company_remote`) I had to first fetch from that remote via `git fetch company_remote`

Comment: Use `git branch -r` to list all branches including currently remote-only branches

Comment: The answer should contain that you have to do `git fetch --all` or `git fetch <specific_remote>` and not just `git fetch`, which seemingly does not do anything at all: the newly created remote will not get fetched, as `git branch -a -v` will show.

Comment: This solution has the advantage of not needing to do a checkout, which you might want to avoid in a script.

Answer (score 50):

If you don't have an existing local branch, it is truly as simple as:

```
git fetch
git checkout <remote-branch-name>
```

For instance if you fetch and there is a new remote tracking branch called `origin/feature/Main_Page`, just do this:

```
git checkout feature/Main_Page
```

This creates a local branch with the same name as the remote branch, tracking that remote branch. If you have multiple remotes with the same branch name, you can use the less ambiguous:

```
git checkout -t <remote>/<remote-branch-name>
```

If you already made the local branch and don't want to delete it, see [How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch).

Comment: `git checkout 1.5-branch` (`remotes/upstream/1.5-branch` is in the output of `git branch -a`) results in `error: pathspec '1.5-branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.` Changing this to `git checkout upstream/1.5-branch` results in detached HEAD and no local branch is created. I think this part of answer is simply wrong. This is with git 2.4.3

Comment: The first command works for me for me in git 1.9.3, even for different remotes. It's possible this behavior has changed. 

The result of your second command is what I'd expect. Without -t, you're not specifying that you want to do anything other than look at that specific version on the remote.

Comment: I concur with @PiotrDobrogost, I believe your statement "This creates a local branch with the same name ..." is mistaken. What fetch *will* do (when called this way) is create a *remote tracking branch* for each branch on the remote. That means a branch on your local repo named `<remote>/<branch>`. A remote tracking branch is read-only, indicating where that branch was on the remote at last fetch. Calling `checkout` on that branch ref puts you in detached HEAD mode, just as Piotr says. Note that specifying the remote branch to fetch avoids creating unwanted remote tracking branches.

Comment: To be clear once more: I am suggesting using the command  
`git checkout feature-branch`.

I am NOT suggesting using the command   
`git checkout origin/feature-branch`


which, as you both have pointed out, will result in an unhelpful detached head.

Comment: much simpler and to the point. Works fine with git 2.8.3 on cygwin.

Comment: Use `git branch -r` to list all branches including currently remote-only branches to make sure branch got fetched. Then checkout.

Answer (score 38):

First of all you have to fetch the remote repository:

```
git fetch remoteName
```

Than you can create the new branch and set it up to track the remote branch you want:

```
git checkout -b newLocalBranch remoteName/remoteBranch
```

You can also use "git branch --track" instead of "git checkout -b" as max specified.

```
git branch --track newLocalBranch remoteName/remoteBranch
```

Comment: If you do `checkout -b` using a remote branch as a starting point, then it's actually unnecessary to then use `--track`.

Comment: Also, as pointed out in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262703/how-to-track-a-new-remote-branch-created-on-github#comment32122710_11262780), if you just do `git checkout <branchname>`, and there is a remote branch with the same name (after you did a `git fetch`), then the local branch will automatically be set up to track the remote one.

Answer (score 9):

When the branch is no remote branch you can push your local branch direct to the remote.

```
git checkout master
git push origin master
```

or when you have a dev branch

```
git checkout dev
git push origin dev
```

or when the remote branch exists

```
git branch dev -t origin/dev
```

There are some other posibilites to push a remote branch.

Comment: Then you take the third option. When the remote branch exists you can create a local branch and track the remote branch :) its the same as the version from max but shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Steps as listed below:

1. First get all the branches that were created after cloning.

```
git fetch
```

2. Now, check what are remote branches

```
git branch -r
```

3. Check where you're in the log history

```
git log --oneline --all --graph
```

4. Assign a new branch to track the remote branch

```
git branch branch_name origin/remote_branch_name
```

5. After that, check your log history either using the step 3 command or `git branch`

Answer (score 1):

I always use this way:

```
git fetch
```

then :

```
git checkout -b branchName origin/branchName
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use GitHub website (fork sync a new branch)

---

**NOTE:**

All other answers solving the problem assumed you have the new branch inside your `origin` remote. For me, It wasn't the case as I have forked the `upstream` repo. So this answer shows how to set it up for a forked repository.

---

You just need to create a new branch that is in sync with a newly created branch on some `upstream` remote.

1. Inside your fork repo, go to `branches` -> `new branch` tab:

[image: Creating new branch from the one on the remote]

In this example, I created a branch `v2` in my fork repo in sync with a
`v2` branch on the `satk0/logstash-exporter` remote (the `upsteam` branch).

2. After updating my fork repo, all I have to do is to pull the newly created branch to my local repo with simple:

```bash
git pull
```

Now, when I check my remote branches:

```bash
git branch -r
```

I finally have the `origin/v2` remote branch and the fork is in sync with the `v2` branch on the `upstream` repo.

3. Now I just need to create a new branch in my local repo
   tracking the remote with:

```bash
git branch v2 origin/v2
```