# How do I pull from a branch with nodegit?

Tags: node.js, git, nodegit

Would appreciate some help with nodegit. I got it to checkout a branch (`branch-development-modular-alpha-2.0.0`) with:

```
var cloneRepo = nodegit
.Clone(cloneURL, repoPath, cloneOptions)
.then(function (repo) {
  repo.getBranch('refs/remotes/origin/' + branch).then(function(reference) {
    repo.checkoutRef(reference);

    // Go through repo's submodules
    nodegit.Submodule.foreach(repo, function (submodule) {
      var submoduleName = submodule.name();
      var submoduleURL = submodule.url();
      var submodulePath = repoPath + "/" + submodule.path();

      // Clone the submodule
      nodegit
      .Clone(submoduleURL, submodulePath, cloneOptions)
      .then(function (repo) {
        // TODO: DO SOMETHING.
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Now I'd like to pull the changes from the same branch and I have something like this however it's not updating with the latest changes from the branch.

```
nodegit
.Repository
.open(path.resolve(__dirname, repoPath))
.then(function (repo) {
  existingRepository = repo;

  return existingRepository.fetchAll(cloneOptions.fetchOpts);
})
.then(function () {
  return existingRepository.mergeBranches('master', 'refs/remotes/origin/' + branch);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You know that under the hood it's just executing git commands right? Is there a reason you're using this module?

Comment: @Darkrum That is incorrect. [NodeGit](http://www.nodegit.org/) is a JavaScript binding around [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) which is a pure C implementation of Git's core features.

Comment: canu share the complete code? m facing issues

Answer (score 1):

A pull would be a fetch + merge.

Except the merge would be origin/master to master.
Or origin/branch to branch.

In your case, the [nodegit `merge` function](http://www.nodegit.org/api/merge/) call should then be:

```
return existingRepository.mergeBranches(branch, 'refs/remotes/origin/' + branch);
```

As [Jamie Counsell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3768332/jamie-counsell) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525298/how-do-i-pull-from-a-branch-with-nodegit/49526155?noredirect=1#comment95034005_49526155):

> I ran into that error too.
>
> It ends up it was because I was retrieving the branch name using `nodegit` as well, which gave something like `origin/refs/heads/master` instead of just `master`.
>
> Calling `branch.shorthand()` got me "`master`"

Comment: Getting '{ Error: no reference found for shorthand 'branch-development-modular-alpha-2.0.0' errno: -3, errorFunction: 'Reference.dwim' }' :-/

Comment: @ChrisF. Is that branch one already present on the remote side?

Comment: The branch is present on the remote, but on local even though I checkedOut the branch I can only see "master". Am I supposed to create the branch locally first?

Comment: @ChrisF. locally, can you do in command line `git branch -avv`?

Comment: I am getting this: * (HEAD detached at origin/branch-development-modular-alpha-2.0.0)
  master
  remotes/origin/branch-development-modular-alpha-2.0.0
  remotes/origin/master

Comment: You need to create a local branch first. Checking out a remote branch will detach `HEAD`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262780/749719).

Comment: @rcjsuen Here, 'branch' is a local branch (that must indeed be checked out). I merge a remote branch in it.

Comment: @VonC Sorry, I was trying to explain to Chris why his `HEAD` was in a detached state. Your answer/code looks fine, yes.

Comment: @ChrisF. I ran into that error too. It ends up it was because I was retrieving the branch name using nodegit as well, which gave something like `origin/refs/heads/master` instead of just `master`. Calling `branch.shorthand()` got me `"master"`.

Comment: @JamieCounsell Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the [pull example](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/examples/pull.js) in nodegit repo:

```js
var nodegit = require("../");
var path = require("path");

var repoDir = "../../test";

var repository;

// Open a repository that needs to be fetched and fast-forwarded
nodegit.Repository.open(path.resolve(__dirname, repoDir))
  .then(function(repo) {
    repository = repo;

    return repository.fetchAll({
      callbacks: {
        credentials: function(url, userName) {
          return nodegit.Cred.sshKeyFromAgent(userName);
        },
        certificateCheck: function() {
          return 0;
        }
      }
    });
  })
  // Now that we're finished fetching, go ahead and merge our local branch
  // with the new one
  .then(function() {
    return repository.mergeBranches("master", "origin/master");
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log("Done!");
  });
```